# Compiler errors for GCC (via CUDA) intrinsic functions, but I'm not using any

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, cuda, intrinsics

## Problem

I wrote a bunch of small CUDA programs.  Most of them compile fine in debug and release builds.  However, a few fail when compiled in Release mode because various GCC intrinsics are being given the wrong types of pointers.  **But I'm not actually using intrinsics**.  This program partially reproduces my problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h> // To pacify the syntax highlighter
#include <immintrin.h> // NOTE: I don't ever include this header in my real code

__global__ void kernel() {
  // Do nothing
}

using namespace std;

int main() {
  kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
  cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The problem, however, is that in my actual code **I do not include `<immintrin.h>` or use GCC intrinsics of any kind**.  It's possible that  some library code I use does, but I don't know for sure.  If I remove `<immintrin.h>` from this example, the program compiles and runs fine.

The *actual* offenders are [here](https://github.com/JesseTG/CUDA-Practice/blob/master/Chapter6/DumbRayTracer/main.cu) and [here](https://github.com/JesseTG/CUDA-Practice/blob/master/Chapter9/AtomicHistogram/main.cu), if you want to see them.

## Relevant Facts

- I am using the following software:

  - Ubuntu 17.04
  - `nvcc` version 8.0.44
  - `gcc` version 5.4.1
  - `cmake` version 3.8.20170418
- The projects build and run perfectly fine in Debug mode, including the sample program above.
- <s>**Most** of my small CUDA programs compile fine in Release builds, but I can't identify any patterns among the ones that fail.</s>
- The Release build compilation command is as follows:

  - `/usr/bin/g++-5  -std=c++11 -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/DotProduct.dir/DotProduct_generated_main.cu.o CMakeFiles/DotProduct.dir/DotProduct_intermediate_link.o  -o DotProduct -Wl,-Bstatic -lcudart_static -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -ldl -lrt ../../Common/libCommon.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lcudart_static -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -ldl -lrt -Wl,-Bstatic -lcudadevrt -Wl,-Bdynamic -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2 -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL`
- The full build log is too large to attach, but can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/22080EFK).  Here's a relevant sample of the errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/avx512fintrin.h(9533): error: argument of type "void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "long long *"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/avx512fintrin.h(9542): error: argument of type "void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "long long *"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/avx512pfintrin.h(54): error: argument of type "const void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const long long *"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/avx512pfintrin.h(62): error: argument of type "const void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const int *"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/avx512pfintrin.h(70): error: argument of type "const void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const long long *"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/avx512pfintrin.h(78): error: argument of type "const void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const int *"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/avx512pfintrin.h(86): error: argument of type "void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const long long *"
```

- <s>The error log does not say who is actually using these intrinsics.</s>
- As it turns out, the sequence of headers is as follows: `<random>` -> `<opt_random.h>` -> `<x86intrin.h>` -> `<immintrin.h>` -> (every other header mentioned in the error log).  My new goal is now to enable all the usual optimizations *except* those which intrinsics.

Comment: you need to add explicit casts to the incompatible types, i.e. myLongLongPtr = (long long *)myVoidPtr;

Comment: @Serge Where?  I'm not actually using those functions and I don't know who is.

Comment: CUDA doesn't support your compiler version or operating system. http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#axzz4lB5unFj4

Comment: Upgrading to CUDA 8.0.61 doesn't help...

Comment: I will repeat myself more explicitly. No version of CUDA 8 supports Ubuntu 17, nor does it support the canonical gcc 5.4-1 build you are using

Comment: ...So I have to downgrade my Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Everything is guaranteed to work if you use a supported operating system and host compiler. It isn't guaranteed to work if you don't.

Comment: I'm trying something with docker.  If it works out I'll answer my own question with my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is likely an `nvcc` bug stemming from CUDA's stated lack of support for my particular system configuration.  I filed a report [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia_bug/1952503) (you need to be logged in to see it).

For now, I worked around it by not using anything that requires intrinsics.  In my case I used [Thrust's random number generators](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__random.html) instead of [the standard library's](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).  Someone I talked to suggested that I could also separate my host and device code more carefully such that the source files processed by `nvcc` don't ever include `<immintrin.h>`.  Haven't tried it but for those in the future who see this, it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with GCC, it is simply nvcc being not compatible with gcc.

The following is a simple walkaround without messing with system file.

It should be safe to do it if **your CPU doesn't have avx512 support**.

1. copy `immintrin.h` from `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/` to wherever you want.
2. comment out all includes of avx512*.h.
3. supply the include directory to host compiler (do it with nvcc and then propagate it to gcc) and override the system one.

You can use the following cmake code to safely do so.

```
# Otherwise, avx512*intrin.h error: argument of type "const void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const float *", etc...
if(CUDA_VERSION STREQUAL "8.0" AND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
  execute_process(COMMAND ${CUDA_HOST_COMPILER} -dumpversion OUTPUT_VARIABLE
                  TEMP_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER_VERSION)

  if(${TEMP_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_EQUAL "5.5" OR
     ${TEMP_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER_VERSION} VERSION_GREATER "5.5")
    # maybe simply downgrade the host compiler
    # set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc-4.9")
    set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-Xcompiler -I${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/fix-cu80-gcc5;${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}")
    message(WARNING " CUDA 8.0 does not works well with GCC == 5.5.0 due to AVX512 intrinsics.\n"
                    " Will use\n"
                    "   include/fix-cu80-gcc5/immintrin.h\n"
                    " as a replacement of\n"
                    "   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/immintrin.h\n")
  endif()
  unset(TEMP_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER_VERSION)
endif()
```

If your CPU does support avx512, you might need supply a bunch of `-mno-avx512f -mno-avx512pf ...` flags to explicitly disable them.

Comment: `-march=native -mno-avx512f` should disable all other AVX512 extensions; they others all depend on the AVX512-Foundation extension.  Just like `-mno-avx` also disables AVX2 and FMA.  Unless nvcc works very differently from gcc/clang options...